Interference pattern with known photon path
I read about the Delayed-choice quantum eraser experiment and came up with an idea. As we know, if we can determine which slit the photon passed through, we cannot observe an interference pattern. But I intend to challenge this.
My setup is almost identical to the original experiment. The difference is that the second entangled photon will travel for a whole minute to an ordinary mirror, then take another minute to return, and only after that will it pass through the half-silvered mirror and head towards the detectors — this will happen almost two minutes after the signal photon hits the main screen detector.
If we run this setup, everything will happen as in the classic experiment: despite the two-minute delay, if the second photon hits the detectors that erase path information, we see the signal photon land in a region corresponding to the interference pattern, and conversely, if the path information is preserved, the interference disappears.
Thus, we still cannot observe interference while knowing the paths of the photons. But! If we instruct the computer to: launch the photon, and if the signal photon hits a point corresponding to the interference pattern, remove the half-silvered mirror from the path of the second photon within a minute, allowing it to reach the detectors that reveal the path of the first photon.
By running this experiment repeatedly, the computer will be able to construct an interference pattern where we know through which slit each signal photon passed. Checkmate! What do you think?

Can you provide a diagram or a source so that we all have the same understanding of the original experiment that you mention?

I'll add it as soon as I can.

The link is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser                         You will find the picture of original  experiment in the sub-item "The experiment of Kim et al. (1999) ".

I think the quantum eraser pattern is actually 4 sub-fringes blotted into a seemingly unified pattern: polarization vertical (or horizontal) photons passing through slit 1 (or slit 2). None of the 4 fringes individually are gap-free, so only when all 4 fringes are blotted together can the gaps (interference pattern) "disappear". Then, no matter how you slice those sub-statistics, if you collect just the blots from photons that pass through slit 1, you still get fringes. If you collect just the blots from the vertically polarized photons, you still get fringes, They are just shifted a little.

I apologize, I described my experiment incorrectly. It does not correspond to the picture. I will correct it soon. And regarding the fact that the resulting image, although not an interference one, will be the sum of several different patterns, I understand. However, in my version of the experiment, this is taken into account.

@YevheniiShyder If you manage to find out the paths for each photon (congratulations!), and reconstruct just those cases e.g. photons (both vertically and horizontally polarized photons) that pass through slit 1, then yes the fringe gaps will become very faint and almost un-discernable to the eye. But the gaps are there in principle because we are in this case just superimposing 2 fringe patterns out of the complete originally 4 patterns. So yes forensic detective work can certainly help to isolate the sub-internal fringe patterns.

Increasing the delay time alone from 8 ns to 2 minutes won't change anything about the essential results. So it should be obvious that nothing ever changes for the D3/D0 or D4/D0 patterns, since they always yield which slit information and interference is never a factor.  But potentially, you might expect that something could change - or perhaps a contradiction arises - related to the D1/D0 (interference) or D2/D0 (anti-interference) patterns.
So you'll use this extra time to choose whether there is to be interference or not for those detectors (in coincidence with D0 of course).  Let's analyze from the perspective of the D1 detector (which shows interference).
Creating an interference pattern at D1 requires the BSc to be in place so that you can't tell which slit the photon came through (i.e. could be via either path).  And if there is instead no BSc in place, there is no interference pattern formed because the photon could ONLY have arrived from the red/upper path.  Thus we'd expect the D1/D0 pattern would look exactly like the D4/D0 pattern.  For that to be true, the relative frequency of hits at D1 and D4 must be the same at each horizontal (x) position of the D0 detector.
But you want to condition the decision for there to be interference (or not) based on the x position where D1 pattern is distinctly higher (i.e. a peak) per the D1/D0 coincidences with interference.  Yours is the "delayed choice on steroids" option.  But all that happens is that the D1/D0 pattern for the subset where you allow interference to occur will look like the normal D1/D0 pattern; but the D1/D0 pattern for the subset where you don't allow interference to occur will change to look like the D4/D0 pattern.
In other words: You will be able to tell after the fact from looking at the D1/D0 pattern whether you have interference - i.e. whether the BSc is in place - or not.  If they had run the experiment without BSc in place and included those results, this would have been obvious.  I could not locate an experiment with that exact setup that did show that variation.  I did find this well-known double slit experiment using entangled photons, you may be able to discern my point from the paper:
A double-slit quantum eraser
Walborn et al, 2008
At any rate, there is no contradiction between theory and experiment.  Delayed choice experiments never demonstrate any change in outcome by changing ordering or delay time. You may benefit from the following roundup on the subject:
Delayed-choice gedanken experiments and their realizations
Ma et al (28 pages)

Nice answer (+1) In the Kim (1999) setup (figure 2 in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser ), it seems the D1 and D2 subsets are actually sifting the photons by their respective vertical vs. horizontal polarizations, which cause the interference fringes to show up, do you think so?
